# Connecting to postgresql gives password authentication failed

Tags: python, django, psycopg2, webfaction

0
Hi, i'm new to **django**. i'm building a **django** project on `server Webfaction`. i got an error when i do "python manage.py sync":

```
 > Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 10, in
 > <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File
 > "//home/xx/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/init.py", line 443, in
 > execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File
  "//home/xx/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/init.py", line 382, in
 > execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File
 > "//home/xx/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in
 > run_from_argv self.execute(*args, options.dict) File
 > "//home/xx/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in
 > execute output = self.handle(*args, options) File
 > "//home/xx/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in
 > handle return self.handle_noargs(options) File
 > "//home/xx/lib/python2.7/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py",
 > line 57, in handle_noargs cursor = connection.cursor() File
 > "//home/xx/lib/python2.7/django/db/backends/init.py", line 306, in
 > cursor cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor()) File
 > "//home/xx/lib/python2.7/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py",
   > line 177, in _cursor self.connection = Database.connect(conn_params)
 > File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/init.py", line 179,
 > in connect connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
 > 
  > psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for
 > user "postgres"
```

and actually in my db setting, i'm using another account (not postgres), why it ask password for `postgres`?

BTW, do i need to install `psycopy2` on `webfaction`? 
Previous it works when i create new db. but now when i try `django auth` and create a new user, it throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, stupid me. forgot to modify database settings after pulling the project from repo.